# Comparing adjacement array elements

Tags: java, arrays, element

I'm trying to work out the difference in adjacent pairs of array elements, and then add the differences together, this is the method I'm using to do this.

I'm trying to split the original array into two smaller arrays and then subtract elements of the smaller arrays which will indirectly workout the difference of my initial array. the diffrences get stored on a last array which adds my differences together....

```
 public static int changeinx(int array1[],int sum) { 
 int n = array1.length;  
int y[];
int u[];
int c[]; 
c = new int [n/2];
y = new int [n/2]; // no. of arrays equal to 1/2 of array1, since two elements subtracted.
u = new int [n/2];
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i += 2 ) { 
y[i] = array1[i]; 
}

for(int i = 1 ; i < n ; i += 2) { 
u[i] = array1[i]; 
}

for(int i = 0 ; i < n/2 ; i++ ) { 
c[i] = Math.abs( u[i] - y[i] ) ;
}

for(int r = 0 ; r < c.length ; r++ ) { 

    sum = sum + c[r];  //adding all the differences up, since abs has been taken
    }

return sum ;
}
```

Why is this not working? :(

Answer (score 0):

This loop never ends:

```
for(int p = 0 ; p < n ; i++ ) {
    y[p] = Math.abs(x); //trying to the difference as x, and asign to array y[]
}
```

Since `p` and `n` never change during the loop, if `p < n` is not true when the loop starts, it will never be true, and the loop will never end.

---

> I'm trying to work out the difference in adjacent pairs of array elements, and then add the differences together, this is the method I'm using to do this.

If I understood the problem description correctly, this can be implemented much simpler:

```
public static int changeinx(int[] arr) {
    int sumOfDiffs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        sumOfDiffs += Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i + 1]);
    }
    return sumOfDiffs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a major flaw in this loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    int x = array1[i] - array1[i+1] ;
```

Let me give an example to illustrate this further, say we have an array

```
array1 = 25 15 55 12
```

the above loop at first iteration would do 25-15
in the 2nd iteration do 15-55
and 3rd iteration do 55-12

So now running this loop on  an array of 4 elements would yield an array with 3 elements not at all conforming to your n/2 formula.

From my understanding of your problem I think your intention is to do 25-15 in the first loop
55-12 in the 2nd loop and end it, as to how you would go about doing it I leave it to you to figure out

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've edited my code to fit around this problem.